# Extjs 7.2: Rendering issue on panel collapse

Tags: extjs, extjs7

### Issue

I have a locking grid with a panel underneath it. When the bottom panel is collapse the grid doesn't get rendered properly.

### To Note

1. This only started occurring after adding pageSize to the grid's store
2. If I lower the pageSize below 48 or above 57 there are no issues (depending on the screen size) (pretty wild)
3. If I remove locking from the grid the issue seems to go away
4. There is a large delay when clicking collapse (2 seconds), this may be the cause for the rendering issues
5. See images below depicting the issue
6. The grid and the lower panel are items of an outer panel like this

   ```
   {
       xtype: 'panel',
       items: [
           {
                xtype: 'grid',
                enableLocking: true
           },
           {
                xtype: 'panel'
           }
       ]
   }
   ```

### What I tried

1. Suspending layouts on the beforecollapse event and then resuming on the collapse event
2. Suspending events on beforecollapse and resuming on collapse
3. Suspending the locking grid's layouts on before and resuming on after
4. Stepping through the extjs code to try to see what the cause would be

#### What could be the cause and possible solution of this issue?

[image: panel expanded]

[image: panel collapsed]

Comment: You can try to specify a layout (layout hbox/vbox align stretch) and add flex to the child components. For a better answer it would be great if you would be able to create a fiddle.

Comment: @hwsw I ended up placing the panel on the side (east). We were having too many rendering issues with south.